# .Net-Core Log out of Oauth

Tags: c#, oauth, .net-core

I've created an application which uses OAuth to login to Coinbase.  My startup configuration looks like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = COINBASE_AUTH_ID;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOAuth(COINBASE_AUTH_ID, options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration["Coinbase:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Coinbase:ClientSecret"];
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-coinbase");

    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize?meta[send_limit_amount]=1";
    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/token";
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/user";

    COINBASE_SCOPES.ForEach(scope => options.Scope.Add(scope));

    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:coinbase:avatar", "avatar_url");

    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
            request.Headers.Add("CB-VERSION", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
            var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            context.RunClaimActions(user);
        }
    };
});
```

When a user logs in I return a challenge result and let the default authentication do it's work.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "/")
{
    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to logout but when I call Signout on the base controller nothing is happening.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Logout()
{
    this.SignOut();
    return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
}
```

How can I log out of oauth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more graceful way of doing this but for now.  I found I can call the `SignOut` method on the HTTPContext

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
    return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
}
```